# How to create a line graph of data points grouped by month in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/02/2022 |
| 2 | 1/07/2022 |
| 3 | 2/14/0222 |

And so on

I have a dataframe that looks like this with an ID and a date for the occurrence. I want to create a line graph that shows how many occurrences happen over time and grouped by month. For example by month 1, there were 2 occurrences. By month 2 there were 3 occurrences because it includes all previous occurrences up to that point.

I tried to use group by but it didn't work as it didn't aggregate up for each month it just had individual occurrences in the month.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- the data should be grouped by year/month and not just month
- the data is as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end which is slightly modified from the question fixing the year in the last row

we have

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  count(DATE = as.yearmon(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  mutate(cum_count = cumsum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(DATE, cum_count)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: screenshot]

Depending on what is wanted the ggplot part could be replaced with:

```
ggplot(aes(DATE, ymin = 0, ymax = cum_count)) + 
  geom_linerange() +
  geom_point(aes(y = cum_count)) +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, DATE = c("1/02/2022", "1/07/2022", "2/14/2022"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "error in usemethod(" as.quoted"): no applicable method for this applied to an object of class "yearmon"".

Comment: Start a fresh session of R. Copy and paste the code in the Note into it.  Then copy and paste the code in the body of the answer.

Comment: You can also copy and paste the same into https://rdrr.io/snippets/ and press Run for a second confirmation that it works.